# How to link a string to a datagridview in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I have a dataset that contains multiple values. With Regex, I could take specific rows from the datatable BLABLA. I stored them in the string `answer`.
Now I want to display `answer` in a datagridview.
This is how one line in `answer` looks like:

> A24.06.2018 13:20:34BLABLA    11/1110 A 2S3/11 
>   1234C:\Users\someone\Desktop\file

The datagridview already contains the needed columns. The lines need to fit in the columns that means they need to be split according to the columns.I never worked with DataSource, so I don't know how it should look like.

I already tried to display `answer` in a MessageBox to see if I have the values that I searched for and I do. But when I try `ErrorsDGV.DataSource = answer` nothing happens.

```
Dim answer As String = ""
Dim myregex As Regex = New Regex("S[0-6]")

Dim SearchRows() As DataRow = datasetB.Tables("BLABLA").Select().
Where(Function(r) myregex.IsMatch(r.Item("Data"))).ToArray()

For k As Integer = 0 To SearchRows.Length - 1
    If answer = "" Then
        answer = String.Join("", SearchRows(k).ItemArray())
    Else
        answer = answer & vbNewLine & String.Join("", SearchRows(k).ItemArray())

    End If
Next

ErrorsDgV.DataSource = answer
```

What am I doing wrong? How does a DataSource have to look like to be used as a source for a DataGridView?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You bind table to datagridview, if you want string then add it to cells or add whole row with it. Datagridview1(C,R).Value = yourstring, or dgv1.rows.add(string1,string2,...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the question by using `CopyToDataTable` and by changing SearchRows to a `DataTable` instead of a `DataRow` as you can see below:

```
Dim SearchRows As DataTable = datasetB.Tables("BLABLA").Select().
    Where(Function(r) myregex.IsMatch(r.Item("Data"))).ToArray().CopyToDataTable
```

Then I used SearchRows as my DataSource

```
ErrorsDgV.DataSource = SearchRows
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this code:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To SearchRows.Length - 1
    If answer = "" Then
        answer = String.Join("", SearchRows(k).ItemArray())
    Else
        answer = answer & vbNewLine & String.Join("", SearchRows(k).ItemArray())

    End If
Next
```

You already have the rows you want to display in here:

```
Dim SearchRows() As DataRow = datasetB.Tables("BLABLA").Select().
Where(Function(r) myregex.IsMatch(r.Item("Data"))).ToArray()
```

So set the grid datasource to this:

```
ErrorsDgV.DataSource = SearchRows
```

Comment: okay thank you, but how does the datagridview know how to parse the line in `SearchRows` into the right columns? Now again nothing happens.. the DataGridView stays empty.